# How to split zip file into multiple valid zip files?

Tags: python, bash, shell, split, zip

`coreutils`'s `split` can split any files. Therefore, it can split a .zip file into multiple files. But the ouput files are not valid zip files any more. This can be a problem when other output files are not available, as a single output file can not be used on its own.

This case can happen, for example, in a slow network, only some files are downloaded but other files take more time to download. But users want to see the initial transfered file.

Is there a good/concise way to split a .zip file into multiple valid .zip files?

I could make my own shell script to unzip the input .zip file and the select the appropriate subsets to compress them into multiple .zip files.

But since this task should be commonly encounted, I am wondering if there is any better way to do so. Thanks.

Comment: Why some files are to be present, and others aren't? If you split your file, how would you know when all zip files were unpacked?

Comment: See the update.

Comment: I have a similar question. I want to split up a large .gz file into smaller ones (which each contain n*4 lines), but could not find a straightforward answer yet. So if you already found a solution to your problem let me know. :)

Comment: I have a similar requirement, I am looking for an utility that can split the larger .zip file into smaller valid .zip files of specified size intelligently. I can iterate through all the file sizes within and split those instead and create separate zip files, but don't want to make it complex

Answer (score 0):

The [`zip(1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zip) utility can take an existing zip archive, and create a new one split up into multiple files. Example:

```
$ zip -U -s 100k -O new.zip old.zip
```

will split the zip file into 100 kilobyte files named `new.z01`, `new.z02`, ..., `new.zip`. Then `unzip new.zip` will automatically read the split files when extracting the archive. Sometimes missing split fragments can be recovered from; read up on the `-F` option.

Comment: I don't think you get the point of my question. The question is each split file should be unzipped independently from others.

Comment: When unzipping the smaller files, do you need all of them, or can they be unzipped independently? I'm trying to handle my large zip files from exporting videos from iCloud.